# SQL Server 2014 not replicating NEW non-clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have an instance of SQL Server 2014 running replication. I have selected the option to copy nonclustered indexes on all tables:

[image: copy nonclustered indexes setting]

When this was first enabled, all existing nonclustered indexes were replicated, but since then no new nonclustered indexes have been replicated.

Have I missed a config somewhere? Or is it necessary to manually replicate new nonclustered indexes each time they are created?

The `replicate_ddl` option (for publishing schema changes) is already enabled on the publication subscription: (Publication Properties -> Subscription Options)

[image]

The `schema_option` value on all tables is `0x00000000080350DF` which breaks down to (if I am not mistaken):

[image]

Which indicates that the option to `Generate corresponding nonclustered indexes` (0x40) is enabled

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with replication, but i think there's an option to have it replicate ddl changes. Is that turned on?

Comment: @BenThul - thanks for the idea, it seemed like it was going to be a winner... unfortunately `replicate_ddl` option is already turned on :( I have updated my question with that info

Comment: What is the value for sysarticles.schema_option as compared with the breakdown of the bitmask in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 (look for @schema_option in there)?

Comment: @BenThul - I have updated my question with that info. I hope I understood your question correctly :)